# Authenticate with Firebase Using Email Link (In Android)

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

Now, I'm following this - (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth)

Using this code,

```
ActionCodeSettings actionCodeSettings =
                    ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
                            // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
                            // URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
                            .setUrl("https://MYPROJECTNAME.page.link/SOMESTRING")
                            // This must be true
                            .setHandleCodeInApp(true)
                            .setAndroidPackageName(
                                    "com.example.MYPROJECTNAME",
                                    false, /* installIfNotAvailable */
                                    "12"    /* minimumVersion */)
                            .build();
```

I sent email successfully.

I set URL with Dynamic Link I made, `"https://MYPROJECTNAME.page.link/..."`.

And when I open the link in email, my app is opened successfully.

But I have a problem with this code

```
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String emailLink = "";
    if( intent.getData() != null ){
        emailLink = intent.getData().toString();
        Log.d("DYNAMIC", "INTENT: " + emailLink);
    }
    else{
        Log.d("DYNAMIC", "No INTENT");
        return;
    }

    // Confirm the link is a sign-in with email link.
    if (auth.isSignInWithEmailLink(emailLink)) {
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

`auth.isSignInWithEmailLink(emailLink)` returned false, so cannot login.

When app is opened with the link in email, I checked `intent.getData().toString()`(String emailLink) with Log.d() and it was `"https://MYPROJECTNAME.firebaseapp.com"`.

Maybe It is wrong emailLink with `isSignInWithEmailLink()`...

Is there something that I missed?
What's proper thing with isSignInWithEmailLink()?